# Thread waiting for signal but never gets it, because of mutex lock

Tags: multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

So i am making a program with 1 main thread(my main), which creates a second one. The second one should wait for a signal and then run. Main waits of course to join.

I have a problem in understanding how my main can lock mutex, and then my thread will lock it too and wait for signal. I mean that is the "guideline" everyone gives on how to do it but I don't see how it works. Since main locks mutex, then thread will always come to a locked muted and wait for mutex to be unlocked, no? That way, signal will be sent before thread has acquired mutex and has blocked in wait(so it will never be waken). But then again it is required to lock mutex in order to wait for the variable... Pls help.
This is the code, it creates a loop because threadfunction blocks in wait..

```
static pthread_mutex_t mtx;
pthread_cond_t cond;

void *threadfunction(void* arg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mtx);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}

int main(void){
    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond,NULL);

    pthread_t tthread;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

    pthread_create(&tthread,NULL,threadfunction,NULL);

    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    pthread_join(tthread,NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably one detail you missed in `pthread_cond_wait` is that it releases the mutex when it starts waiting.

The scenario for condition variables is that when a thread needs to wait for a condition to happen, it locks a mutex and calls `wait`. This will release the mutex so other threads can go into their critical sections, change conditions, and `signal` so the waiting threads can wake up.

In your example, you create the thread when the mutex is already locked, so the thread has no chance of passing the first lock. That means when you signaled the thread, it wasn't waiting.

Comment: I know how that works. What I dont understand is: main locks mutex->creates thread->signals->unlocks, but by the time that thread is on trying to lock mutex,main has not unlocked it,so again how can it wait for it when it is signaled?

Comment: The key here is: the thread has to be waiting before main locks and signals the mutex. Start the thread, and wait for a condition in a loop (say, `while(!condition) { pthread_cond_wait(...)}`). Then in main lock the mutex, change the condition and signal. The way you setup your test code is misleading you,